# How to join the orders and returns together into a single file

Tags: python, csv, join, jupyter-notebook

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2PpV.png)

How do I join two csv files in python using Jupyter Notebook? the Order id tab is what both of them have in common.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

# Loading in my CSV data for Orders, People, and Returns
orders_df = pd.read_csv('orders.csv')  
people_df = pd.read_csv('people.csv')  
returns_df = pd.read_csv('returns.csv')

#'ORDER_ID' is the common field between the two datasets (orders and returns)
merged_data = your_existing_data.merge(orders_df, left_on='ORDER_ID', right_on='ORDER', how='inner')
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)